# Prevent Improper-Input-Handling attack

Tags: java, security, tomcat7, hostheaders

I'm trying fix a site vulnerability, it is  "Improper Input Handling" attack raised by WhiteHat. Let's say my website is [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) and there is hacker's website [www.hacker.com](http://www.hacker.com)

whenever there is a request send to [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) with modified "Host" header point to [www.hacker.com](http://www.hacker.com), my site will create a redirect to [www.mywebsite.com](http://www.mywebsite.com) along with whatever the url it was. To fix this I tried below tomcat virtual host configuration but still it's redirecting to other website.

```
<Host name="defaultlocalhost" appbase="whatever">
           <!-- allow addresses to these host -->
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
                    allow=".*\.mywebsite1\.com|.*\.mywebsite2\.com"/>
</Host>
```

**So, my question is, is it the right approach to prevent this host header attack ? If yes, what I did wrong that still not working? (The ultimate goal is, if it is not the legit Host that been passed in, the request should be discard/ignored/return 404 but not redirect with 302)**

Comment: Read https://serverfault.com/questions/850955/tomcat-virtual-host-to-prevent-improper-input-handling-attack again, the `defaultlocalhost` host config shouldn't have a `Valve`.

Comment: @tgdavies As per your comment I tried removing Valve.  Now in my server.xml I have only <Host name="defaultlocalhost" appbase="whatever"></Host> but after I test through below curl command it's still returns 302. Expecting 404.  Below curl command I am using for testing.                                  Curl command:                                                                                                                  
curl -isk -H "host: host.whitehatsec.com" "https://mywebsite1.com/43535333?host_header=host"

Comment: For the trick you are using to work, the `<Engine>` containing your host, must have `defaultHost="defaultlocalhost"`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Can you elaborate , Is this what you are referring.         
                                      `<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="defaultlocalhost">
      <Host name="defaultlocalhost" appbase="whatever"/>
      </Host>
    </Engine>`
Do I need to keep both Engine configuration pointing to localhost and defaultlocalhost, Is this right? Any more changes needed?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Tomcat Virtual Host to prevent Improper-Input-Handling attack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44054591/tomcat-virtual-host-to-prevent-improper-input-handling-attack)

Comment: Yes, the `defaultHost` attribute must point to the empty host configuration your created. If you leave the _"default"_ value `localhost`, all requests for unknown hosts will still go to your `localhost` virtual host.

Comment: Yes I tried "allowHostHeaderMismatch" didn't work ,new Engine with defaultHost also I added still it's redirecting.